# Displaying Current Sub-Category name on Magento Product page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I currently working on a magento store where i need to display the name and url of current subcategory of the product in the product page. Till now i have come up with the following code.

```
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>

                <?php 


                foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id):

                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id) 



                ?>


                <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>


                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But the problem is this displays all the categories the product is assigned to. All i need is the only subcategory's name in which the product is assigned to. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the products assigned to only one or multiple categories?

Comment: products are assigned to multiple categories..

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways. Quickest and easiest may to use thr Magentk Registry. So try code below:

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category')
```

Or

```
$categoryIds = Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryIds();
```